# Linking in views with multiple fields displayed

Tags: views, navigation

I am making a view in Drupal 7 to display grants: the name, the description, the amount of the grant, and the due date for submission.

It's easy to make a view that displays the name, the amount and the date in each row of a table, with the name linking to the full node display.

I've also learned how to display the description below the title, using the rewrite rules for the title, like:

```
[title]

[body]
```

What I want is having only the title as link to the full node, not all the text. Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

---

## Format

- Format: table
- Show: fields

## Fields

- Content: Title

  - under "settings" check "exclude from display"
- Content: Path

  - under "settings" check "exclude from display"
- Content: Grant Amt
- Content: Due date
- Content: Body

  - under "settings" choose to rewrite output as follows:

    <a href="[path]" title="grant page for [title]">[title]</a>
    <br />
    [body]

---

... and then add filter and sort criteria as desired.

Comment: But I would like to maintain the nice table formatting, and this would just display each one in a block of text, wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure what formatting you have on your display currently. If you prefer a table or an HTML list of fields to the unformatted list, you could use one of those instead. You could also use your stylesheet to style the view once it's created. This advice is rather vague; if you provide more detail about the effect you're trying to achieve/maintain I might be able to help further.

Comment: This is the test page with the view so far:
http://preparewisconsin.org/grants

I like everything about this view, other than that both the title and the description are part of the link to the node - I want just the title to be the link. I built it as described above. But I don't see a way to have just the title be the link, using the Views settings.

Comment: Ah. I see. I will amend my answer to accommodate.